# TestNG: Is running classes in parallel thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, testng

When i run my test classes in parallel, the number of failed tests are higher than if i run the test classes serialized.  I log a lot to the console for debugging purposes, but it is almost useless when running in parallel as everything logged is jumbled/out of order.

Before i try and fix the logging issue so i can debug better, i was wondering, if I set `parallel="classes"`, does it guarantee thread safety?  I assume if I set `parallel="tests"` two methods could try to access the same object in scope, leading to thread safety issues.

ie:

```
<suite name="test" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">
```

Comment: If this is indeed the case then your unit tests are not unit tests; unit tests are supposed to be run in isolation. Do you have an example of tests which fail when they are run "in parallel"?

Comment: These are not unit tests, these are actual functional/regression runs.

Comment: I figured it out, its the static variables causing problems.  Need to replace/refactor them.

Comment: @Greg can you explain? I'm running into the same problem with my tests. Which static variables are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From TestNG Documentation [5.10.2 - Parallel tests, classes and methods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests):

> The *parallel* attribute on the  tag can take one of following values:
>
> ```xml
> <suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
> ```
>
> ```xml
> <suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
> ```
>
> ```xml
> <suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
> ```
>
> ```xml
> <suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
> ```
>
> - **`parallel="methods"`**: TestNG will run all your test methods in separate threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they will respect the order that you specified.
> - **`parallel="tests"`**: TestNG will run all the methods in the same  tag in the same thread, but each  tag will be in a separate thread. This allows you to group all your classes that are not thread safe in the same  and guarantee they will all run in the same thread while taking advantage of TestNG using as many threads as possible to run your tests.
> - **`parallel="classes"`**: TestNG will run all the methods in the same class in the same thread, but each class will be run in a separate thread.
> - **`parallel="instances"`**: TestNG will run all the methods in the same instance in the same thread, but two methods on two different instances will be running in different threads.

As such, if by "thread safe" you mean there won't be more than one TestNG thread interacting with any given test class instance then yes, using "classes" will get you what you want. However, "tests" does not run each test method in its own thread but each `<test>` tag from you testng.xml. The descriptions above should help.

Comment: yes, I meant methods above instead of tests. That "tests" tag is very confusing, I have to keep reminding myself to look at it from the test suite file, and not the actual interpreted name.